# React: 'paypal' is not defined

Tags: paypal

I copied this code straightly from [the official page](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/configure-payments/single-page-app/) of PayPal with correct client credentials. Here is my code:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>React App</title>
    <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=SECRET"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

YourComponent.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"


const PayPalButton = paypal.Buttons.driver("react", { React, ReactDOM });

 
class YourComponent extends React.Component {
  createOrder(data, actions) {
    return actions.order.create({
      purchase_units: [
        {
          amount: {
            value: "135",
          },
        },
      ],
    });
  }

  onApprove(data, actions) {
    return actions.order.capture();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <PayPalButton
        createOrder={(data, actions) => this.createOrder(data, actions)}
        onApprove={(data, actions) => this.onApprove(data, actions)}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default YourComponent;
```

App.js

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import YourComponent from './YourComponent';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <YourComponent/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

When I run it, it says PayPal at line 4:22 is not defined. I guess it is a silly error or might be my misunderstanding on the API too. Can anyone tell me what I can do?

Comment: presumably this ap is addding `paypal` to the global object after your react runs

Answer (score 2):

> `https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=SECRET`

- If you are actually using your REST App's API `secret` as part of the script src, that would be invalid. The REST App's client-id value must be passed here.
- Load the app and check the browser's Developer Tools to make sure the script is actually being loaded successfully.
- Instead of `paypal.Buttons.driver` you can try `window.paypal.Buttons.driver`
- Alternatively, use the official [react-paypal-js module](https://paypal.github.io/react-paypal-js/?path=/docs/example-paypalbuttons--default) instead.

Comment: Well, I am just hiding the client id for privacy reasons. Okay, I an trying that module.

Comment: I would suggest window.paypal.Buttons.driver as the wrapping my app in the official module was breaking specific JavaScript functions but not the complete app